# Redgate Extension for Visual Studio

Tags: database, oracle, visual-studio, redgate, readyroll

I want to know if there is a Redgate Extension for **Oracle databases** in Visual Studio similar to "ReadyRoll SQL Server Database Project" which supports SQL Server databases only ??

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Here at Redgate we have the Deployment Suite for Oracle. It is IDE agnostic, meaning it doesn't matter where you make your database changes, Visual Studio, SQL Developer, Toad etc. The tool words by detecting differences between your dev instance and what's in version control and prompts you to check in the differences.

If you want a ReadyRoll-like experience, in other words, you'd prefer migrations-based deployments over state-based deployments, the best we can offer today is a preview of an integration with Flyway, which is a highly popular and easy-to-use migrations-runner. See the [Migration Script Support](https://documentation.red-gate.com/ddfo/product-roadmap) section of our roadmap for more details on how to try it out.

Comment: The idea is to have an oracle database project by importing an existing database and make the modifications into the project so we can deploy those changes to any database. And as I saw the Deployment Suite for Oracle doesn't give this oppportunity it's more about comparing databases and deploying the changes directly. But in my case, I need to have a database project in Visual Studio so all the team can make changes and check in those modifications in TFS(cauz I'm working with TFS). When deploying the project here the schema comparison should be done to obtain the diff script to be deployed.

Comment: Take a look at the Source Control for Oracle component of the Deployment Suite. You can use this to map a dev DB to a folder of scripts in version control (or a working folder that you check in yourself).

Comment: Yes, I did take a look and as I understood we are making changes on the database directly and not on a database project and the Source Control for Oracle allows to ckeck in those modifications. Returnning to my case, I need to have at the end a diff script which can be deployed on a client database too. I don't know if you got my idea but i want something similar to SSDT.

Comment: The folder of object-level files that Source Control for Oracle saves are the same state files that SSDT creates. You can generate a deployment script by comparing this folder against  your target database using the Schema Compare for Oracle tool (or its command line should you want to automate).